# Limitar a quantidade de colunas de uma tabela HTML pelo PHP

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor Desconto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php 
    $tabela = 'produtos';
    $colunas = 4;
    $limite = 0;
    echo $metodos->listarDados($tabela,$colunas,$limite);
?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Estou querendo criar um método genérico onde através das configurações abaixo, definissem a quantidade de colunas da tabela acima:

```
  $tabela = 'produtos';
  $colunas = 4;
  $limite = 0;
```

Observem que tem a variável **$colunas = 4**, ela corresponde a quantidade de colunas que a tabela HTML deverá ter, ou seja, referentes a Nome, Descrição, Valor e Valor Desconto.

Com isso, chamo o método conforme abaixo:

```
echo $metodos->listarDados($tabela,$colunas,$limite);
```

E o método encontra-se dessa forma:

```
 public function listarDados($tabela,$colunas,$limite)
    {
       $limite = ($limite == 0)?null:"LIMIT".$limite;
       $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM ".$tabela." ".$limite.";");
       $visualizar = '';
       for($c = 0; $c < $colunas; $c++)
       {
         while($pe = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
         {
             $visualizar .= '<tr>';
             // aqui incluir os valores referentes as colunas da tabela
             $visualizar .= '</tr>';
         }
       }      
   return $visualizar; 
    }
```

Pensei em colocar o `for()`, mas vi que isso iria limitar as linhas e não as colunas. Enfim, gostaria de fazer com que, conforme fosse definido a quantidade de colunas na `$colunas`, aparecesse as colunas das tabelas respectivas ao valor incluído na variável.

Comment: A forma de fazer para as colunas é utilizar um `for` sobre o resultado do `mysqli_query`, mas isso implica aceder por posição em vez de nome da coluna,o que não é bom pois força a ordem das colunas no banco, e dificulta no futuro.

Comment: Olá Isac. Teria como me mostrar um exemplo? A ordem das colunas posso colocar também no thead da tabela.

Comment: Pensei que a ordem era a da tabela do banco de dados, mas então a ordem tem de ser a que está dentro do `<thead>` é isso ? Assumindo que existem colunas com o mesmo nome descartando o *casing* ?

Comment: Na verdade o `<thead>` vai seguir a ordem do banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Obtendo colunas por posição

Se a ordem é a mesma que vem da consulta do banco de dados apenas precisa de fazer um `for` especifico dentro da leitura de cada linha da tabela.

Ajustando ao seu código fica algo como:

```
public function listarDados($tabela, $colunas, $limite){
    $limite = ($limite == 0)?null:"LIMIT".$limite;
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM $tabela $limite;");

    $HTMLTabela = '';

    //ler cada linha    
    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $HTMLTabela .= '<tr>';

        //percorrer cada coluna por posição
        for ($i = 0; $i < $colunas; ++$i){
            $HTMLTabela .= '<td>' . $linha[$i] . '</td>';
        }

        $HTMLTabela .= '</tr>';
    }
    return $HTMLTabela; 
}
```

Troquei o nome de algumas variáveis para nomes mais sugestivos. Note que quando constrói a `string` para o SQL não precisa de concatenar as variáveis e pode interpola-las diretamente na `string`, tal como eu tenho. Usei `fetch_array` em vez do `fetch_object` que tinha e obtenho cada coluna com:

```
$linha[$i]
```

Isto porque em cada linha o `fetch_array` devolve um array com chaves definidas para os números e nomes das colunas. Se você der um `print_r` numa `$linha` vê isso mesmo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teste
    [nome] => Teste
    [1] => uma descrição 
    [descricao] => uma descrição
    [2] => 110
    [valor] => 110
    [3] => 20
    [valor_desconto] => 20
)
```

Logo tanto pode aceder pelo nome como pela posição.

Esta ideia torna fácil de mudar a quantidade de colunas que pretende obter, mas por outro lado torna o código rígido, e difícil de manter pois fixa a ordem das colunas. Isto regra geral torna-se um problema no futuro se quiser adicionar ou remover colunas pois quebra esta função que fez (infelizmente falo por experiência própria, que já tive problemas com isto no passado). Nesse caso apenas pode adicionar colunas no fim e nunca remover colunas sob pena de quebrar o código.

## Obtendo colunas com base num array

Uma solução mais flexível para o mesmo cenário(ainda que não tão automática) é passar um array de nomes de colunas a obter:

```
$tabela = 'produtos';
$colunas = Array('nome', 'descricao', 'valor', 'valor_desconto');
$limite = 0;
echo $metodos->listarDados($tabela, $colunas, $limite);
```

Nesse caso a função fica consideravelmente parecida à anterior:

```
public function listarDados($tabela, $colunas, $limite){
    $limite = ($limite == 0)?null:"LIMIT".$limite;
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM $tabela $limite;");
    $HTMLTabela = '';
        
    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $HTMLTabela .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($colunas as $coluna){
            $HTMLTabela .= '<td>' . $linha[$coluna] . '</td>';
        }
            
        $HTMLTabela .= '</tr>';
    }
    return $HTMLTabela; 
}
```

A única alteração foi mesmo o `for` das colunas que passou agora a um `foreach`:

```
foreach ($colunas as $coluna){
    $HTMLTabela .= '<td>' . $linha[$coluna] . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Isac. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar.